# Angular 4 Load the circle.css in the document’s head section

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using Angular 4 and I want to use the circle.css from [cssscript](https://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-circular-percentage-bar/).
 I download the file from the link, put the circle.css inside my something component file but when I use
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="circle.css">`

in my something.component.html.

I get Error:

> zone.js:654 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load circle.css ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load circle.css
>   undefined* Which are the correct   steps I need to follow to use the
>   css file circle.css in my component??

Comment: Are you putting it in the `<head>` of index.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about your architecture but, assume you're using Angular-CLI and you've written the `ng generate component testComponent --module app` command

You should have now some files in your project under the test-component folder:

- test-component.component.ts
- test-component.component.html
- test-component.component.css
- test-component.component.spec.ts

file: **test-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-component',
  templateUrl: './test-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-component.component.css']
})
export class TestComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

so you can hit your target import in the "test-component" folder the circle.css file and add to the list of the styleUrls component  `styleUrls: ['./test-component.component.css','./circle.css']`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the relative path for that file, Webpack will think how to resolve the absolute path for you. 
If the file exists in the same folder then try using `./circle.css` in place of `circle.css`, if instead it's in a sibling *styles* folder you can write `../styles/circle.css`.