# Loading .css & .js files from ./assets folder

Tags: angular

I am loading `.css` & `.js` files from `./assets` folder in certain component:

```
skin_url: './assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray',
language_url : './assets/tinymce/langs/ru.js'
```

This is the path where those files should be load: `http://localhost/dashboard/menu`

When I visit this path: `http://localhost/dashboard/menu` in app start files are loaded perfectly, but when I visit the same path from `http://localhost/dashboard/news` --> `http://localhost/dashboard/menu`, I've got an error:

```
GET http://localhost/dashboard/assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost/dashboard/assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

> What I'm doing wrong?

I don't know how, but somehow the path is changing from `http://localhost/assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css` into `http://localhost/dashboard/assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css`

Comment: You can probably refer to the assets folder directly like I'm doing here: <img class="logo" src="assets/logo.png"/>, no matter where you're typing it.

Comment: I already doing so...

Comment: Ok, suppose I'll do so, then how can I set the `.css` file to ; `skin_url: CSS_PATH,`

Comment: I don't know what you suppose to do. you can add a static path in the -angular-cli.json and webpack is bundling it in the styles.bundle.js, which will be included in the index.html. Just add your css path in the styles array `"styles": [
     "path/to/your/css/file"
],`

Comment: @Daniomi: okay, thanks

Comment: you could take a look at this, it might help: [load custom css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589032/angular-4-load-the-circle-css-in-the-document-s-head-section/46589802#46589802)

Comment: @GianlucaBeritognolo: didn't help...